# Compile shared library with VS2015 : "this client is not compatible with the paired build agent"

Tags: c++, ios, node.js, npm, visual-studio-2015

I created a shared library with **Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Update 1** :
`File > New Project > Templates > Visual C++ > Cross Platform > Shared Library (Android, iOS)`

I got the following project structure by default :

[image: projectStructureScreenShot]

The android project builds successfully. But the issue appears when I try to **compile the iOS project** (the highlighted one on the screenshot).

Since a build agent is needed, I installed it on a Mac using [`npm`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/npm) and [`vcremote`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vcremote) (as explained here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt147405.aspx).

I successfully paired Visual Studio with the Mac by going into `Tools > Options > Cross Platform > C++ > iOS > Pairing`.

But I still get the following error :

> "Build agent request has failed, this client is not compatible with the paired build agent. Client version "1.3.0", build agent version "2.3.0". Supported build agent versions are: "2.0.0 - 2.2.0". Please update vcremote with "npm update vcremote", on the Mac."

On the Mac Terminal I get a similar error message :

> "Visual Studio is incompatible with the current version of this build agent. Please update vcremote using npm."

I did run the `npm update vcremote` command, it is now up to date, but the error still shows up. Moreover it seems that the build agent version is too high regarding the client version.

What do you guys suggest ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was the version of [`vcremote-lib`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vcremote-lib) which was too high (2.3.0). I tried to downgrade only this package but it didn't work, so I downgraded the entire [`vcremote`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vcremote) and it finally worked. Here are the steps I followed to resolve my problem :

### Uninstall [`vcremote`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vcremote) :

*(documentation about the [`npm`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/npm) "uninstall" command : https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/uninstall)*

```
    sudo npm -g uninstall vcremote --save
    sudo npm -g uninstall vcremote-lib --save
```

---

### Check which versions are available :

*(documentation about the [`npm`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/npm) "version" command : https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/version)*

If you don't specify a version number while installing a package the latest version is chosen by default. To check the available versions for a specific package *(here we're talking about [`vcremote`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vcremote) package)* run the following command :

```
    npm view vcremote versions
```

---

### Reinstall a specific version of [`vcremote`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vcremote) :

*(documentation about the [`npm`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/npm) "install" command : https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)*

I didn't want the last one (1.0.8), so I specified a prior version (1.0.6) while running the following command :

```
    sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm vcremote@1.0.6
```

...instead of using the following command provided in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt147405.aspx#Anchor_1) :

```
    sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm vcremote
```

---

### And finally :

Now it's working fine because **vcremote 1.0.6** uses **vcremote-lib 2.0.0** (while **vcremote 1.0.8** used **vcremote-lib 2.3.0**).

Answer (score 0):

(i can't post comments yet...)

With visual studio 2015 update 2 released yesterday you get this error:

> Build agent request has failed, this client is not compatible with the paired build agent. Client version "1.4.0", build agent version "2.0.0". Supported build agent versions are: "2.3.0 - 2.4.0". Please update vcremote with "npm update vcremote", on the Mac.

now need to update to vcremote 1.0.8 (in order to get vcremote-lib 2.0.3):

> sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm vcremote@1.0.8

which brought in vcremote-lib 2.0.3, version 2.0.4 doesn't seem to be available yet

Comment: You're right. I suggest to always try with the last version of `vcremote` and the last version/update of VS. If there's a *"mismatch versions error"* then follow the steps in my solution.